# EnumMap.containsValue(null) returns true JDK 7

Tags: java, enum-map

I found a strange behavior. I m using `JDK 1.7`. 
When I print `map.containsValue(null)`

it returns `true` though I don't have any null value in my MAP.

```
import java.util.EnumMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class EnumMapTest {
    enum EnumType {
        ZERO, ONE, TWO
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<EnumType, Integer> map = new EnumMap<EnumType, Integer>(EnumType.class);
        map.put(EnumType.ZERO, 0);
        System.out.println(map.containsValue(null));
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm getting false with this example. JDK 1.7.0_60 32 bits Windos 8.1

Comment: Try it on Java SE Development Kit 7u2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because it inspects all the values for all the possible keys. In your case

```
map.get(ONE) is null
map.get(TWO) is null
```

In Java 8 it doesn't do this. Instead distinguishes between `null` as in not set and `NULL` which is a value set to null.

Comment: Thanx @Peter lawrey yeah i installed Java 8 and its not... reproducible:)

Comment: @show_stopper I suspect it was a bug in the handling of an edge case.

Answer (score 3):

Its a bug in openjdk implementation. [Consider this link](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-7123229)

Ideally It should give false only 
[See this 1.7 SE](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EnumMap.html#containsValue(java.lang.Object))

It says Returns: true if this map maps one or more keys to this value

for me its giving `false` - running on JRE1.7.0_55

Comment: Try it on Java SE Development Kit 7u2

Comment: I think that this is the correct answer as it is obviously a bug version dependent.